# Linq-To-Sql ORM Update One To many

Tags: c#, orm, linq-to-sql

I am struggling for updating several records at the same time using Linq-to-sql Orm.
The database i have made is as follows:
One Tendering has one or many details.
one TenderingDetails has one or many DetailsOptions.
One Option has One Or Many ConfigDetail.

I was able to create those normally using Linq To Sql.

but when i try to Update i end up having multiple records.
I am having a model class for each of the aforementioned entities, then i pass to the service that update the enitity of Tindering, TinderingDetails, DetailsOptions and OptionConfigDetails

then when i try to Update as follow:

```
the parameters are :
                TenderingModel tenderingModel,
                TenderingDetailsModel tenderingDetailModel,
                List<TenderingOption> optionsList
try
{
     var entity = ModelMapper.GetTenderingEntity(TenderingModel);
     //The next statement is where i got form dataconetxt ->singleordefault 
     //then map the properties one by one
     _unitOfWork.TenderingRepository.Update(entity);
     var tenderingDetailEntity = ModelMapper.GetTenderingDetailEntity(tenderingDetailModel)
    _unitOfWork.TenderingDetailsRepository.Update(tenderingDetailEntity);
    //Update Options
     if (optionsList != null)
                {
                    var optionsEntities = new List<OptionItem>();
                    optionsList.ForEach(o =>
                    {
                    //Just get the Entity from the model
                        optionsEntities.Add(o.GetEntity());
                    });

                    foreach (var item in optionsEntities)
                    {
                        item.ID_Tendering_DETAILS = pricingDetailEntity.ID_Tendering_DETAILS;
                        //Delete the exisiting and config details
                       
                        //delete all configuration details
                        _unitOfWork.OptionConfigurationsRepository.DeleteAllByOptionId(item.ID_OPTION);
                        
                        //Add the new  Config Details
                       
                        item.OptionConfigurationDetails.ToList().ForEach(od =>
                        {

                            _unitOfWork.OptionConfigurationsRepository.Create(od);
                        });

                        _unitOfWork.OptionsRepository.Update(item);
                    }

                }
                //this mainly would submitChanges()
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception($"Error while Updating  the Tendering, details are : {e.Message}");
        }
```

what i was expecting is that i would be updating as follows:

TenderingDetail Entity would be updated by the values from the model,
the options which is a child to the Tendering Detail is to be updated by removing all its config details,
then add new ones along of updating the Options table itself
but what happens is that i would get is added records for the options and for the details instead of updating???

an Edit:

It seems that it is something i do wrong with the Update approach i am using, but i do not know what it is  exactly :
for example the tendering table is having the following columns:

```
Id -> Primary Key
ClientId-> FK
Current Revision -> int value, nullable
some other column values that are having default values , like time stamps , and etc,
```

How i do the Update is, like :

```
public void Update(Tendering tendering)
        {
           var tenderingEntity =  GetTendering ById(pricing.ID_Tendering);

            tenderingEntity .CURRENT_REVISION = tendering.CURRENT_REVISION;
            tenderingEntity .ID_CLIENT = tendering.ID_CLIENT;               
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any Primary keys?  When you have primary keys the existing items get updated (not duplicates). When you do not have a Primary key duplicates can occur.  Suppose you have two rows of apples in database with quantities 10 and 20.  What happens if you update quantity to 15?

Comment: ye sure i do have primary keys : each table has his own primary key, and then i am creating foreign keys for the one to many relationships

Comment: Entity contains classes that map to the  tables in the database.  First make sure the mapping is correct.  Often people change the columns in the database and then forget to refresh the mappings.  When you query a database the classes in c# are filled.  Then when you update the data in the classes that change are put back into the database.  If you add rows in the classes is where issue occur.  The original data is from query is mapped to the rows in the database tables.  But when new rows are added thing can get messed up.

Comment: I have made a brief edit , can you please have a look?

Comment: I usually use if (optionsList.Count() > 0) because it can be zero instead of null.  Where are the two parameters coming from   TenderingModel tenderingModel, TenderingDetailsModel tenderingDetailModel,  You update the database so I'm not sure if the two parameters are synchronized with the database.

Answer (score 0):

From the code supplied, I'm not sure what `_unitOfWork` is here or how you're handling your db context. Typically when duplicate records are saved, it happens when different contexts are used to save the parent and child items or the item was fetched from a context other than the one you are trying to use to save. Double check the implementation of your repository and unit of work to make sure that they are issuing a single Save at the end of the operation and all values are being fetched and saved by the same context instance.

As an aside, your _UnitOfWork feels more like an active record pattern than a true unit of work.